# sharing users across applications with or without devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Context: considering design decisions for an application that maintains Central User records and populates Subordinate applications with new and updated records.

The flow of operations would allow a user to navigate to a Subordinate site,

- create a User via a form in a modal that posts to the Central application
- Central application processes,
- Central application communicates the data created for saving at the Subordinate database via API
- redirect user to another page of the Subordinate site.
  *for updates, the local data is edited and posted to Central server, processes and communicates data via API for saving and redirects user to relevant view page. Both Central and Subordinate application have the same master.key for keeping synched encrypted passwords*

**Direct question**
Two choices are to be made: with or without automatic login.  The latter is straightforward.  But how could the return of the API data allow to create a session on the Subordinate site (with Devise installed)?

**Indirect question**
Devise might be overkill for the subordinate site, as the only requirement is for setting/destroying sessions.  One [possible avenue](https://stevepolito.design/blog/rails-authentication-from-scratch/#step-6-create-current-model-and-authentication-concern) is to create a model Current and Authentication Concern, then a login & logout functions.  Again, what would be required to create the automatic login?

**BlueSky question**
Is there any critical element not being adressed by the above approach?

Comment: I omitted to be more specific about the TLD. The design has to allow for NOT having the same TLD.

Comment: This sounds like you need a Single Sign On (SSO) approach -- an authentication provider app and then all the goodies to share tokens to the consuming apps. This is not a trivial undertaking from scratch -- suggest looking up implementing OAuth for rails. Here's a fairly good intro... https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/oauth2-ruby/